# Events not getting properly displayed in Full Calendar

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

We are using fullcalendar version 3.9 .We have created a event from 8th -12th of Nov in Standard Calendar Events are getting populated properly whereasin fullcalendar is not getting displayed properly like if event from 8th-11th then its displaying 8th- 11th only.

Fullcalendar events:
[image]

Standard calendar events:
[image]

Comment: What is "Standard Calendar" in this context? It's unclear what you mean. Are you talking about an Outlook or Google calendar perhaps, or something else maybe? Also where is your code and data? We cannot fix pictures. Please read [ask] and how to create a [mre] of your issue. As you're fairly new to the site, you should also take the [tour] (I can see from your profile that you didn't do this when you signed up, despite the system prompting you to do so).

Comment: Anyway, at a guess, you've forgotten (or [failed to read](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/event-object)) that event end dates in fullCalendar are **exclusive**. So if you specify the 12th as the end date on an all-day event, it will actually end at 23:59:59 on the 11th.

Comment: Also, last time I posted I remarked that fullCalendar 3 is old and has bugs, and less functionality and slower speed than newer versions. If you're just starting out with fullCalendar, I don't know why you would choose to use this version. I would strongly recommend upgrading to the latest version (5.11.3, at the time of writing).